# Is this API structure HATEOAS compatible?

Tags: api, rest, restful-architecture, hateoas, hypermedia

I'm wondering if the following structure of API links is HATEOAS compatible?

**Especially I'm not sure of /create endpoint**. Should it be at the entry level because user can create a group from there or is it fine to put it in /groups?

What are your thoughts about the rest? It should be also HAL compatible.

```
/groups
  /create
  /detail/{groupId}
    /update
    /delete
    /items
  /search{?page,size,sort}
```

Comment: Why do you put operations (`create`, `detail`, `update`, `delete`, `search`) into URIs? That's RPC, not REST.

Comment: I realised it should be just
POST /groups - to create group
PUT /detail/{groupID} - to update group
DELETE /detail/{groupID} - to delete group

Comment: Yes, that would be better.

Comment: But shouldn't _links provide this kind of URI's anyway?

Comment: But the URIs must not change. Then HTTP verb can change.

Comment: I get it, but is that bad practice to provide GET /detail/{groupId} response with update and delete links which in this case would be the same as the parent?

Comment: No, since the the HTTP verb to be used and specified with the link will be different.

Comment: I can implement other HTTP verb on frontend side. I think this kind of information (update/delete links) still provides some information "what we can do in current state". Am I wrong?

By the way - any good articles about a use of OPTIONS method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HATEOAS (see [Richardson's Maturity Model level 3](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html#level3)) is all about links, so with HAL Browser this would look something like this:

Root:

```
{
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "/api/root"
    },
    "api:group-add": {
      "href": "http://apiname:port/api/group"
    },
    "api:group-search": {
      "href": "http://apiname:port/api/group?pageNumber={pageNumber}&pageSize={pageSize}&sort={sort}"
    },
    "api:group-by-id": {
      "href": "http://apiname:port/api/group/id" (OR "href": "http://apiname:port/api/group?id={id}")
    }
  }
}
```

The add would simply be a POST to that endpoint, and then you'd have 2 GET methods.

Then once you drill down to a particular group (say #1):

```
{
  "Id" : 1,
  "Name" : "test",
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "/api/group/1" (OR "/api/group?id=1")
    },
    "edit": {
      "href": "http://apiname:port/api/group/1"
    },
    "api:delete": {
      "href": "http://apiname:port/api/group/1"
    },
    "api:items-query": {
      "href": "http://apiname:port/api/bonus?groupId=1"
    }
  }
}
```

Here, the edit would simply be a PUT, and then you'll need a DELETE (see level 2 of REST in that same link), as for the items, you probably know best if they are just a property, or another endpoint; you could even embed them to be returned in the same call that's retrieving a group.